# Добавить классы в массив

Tags: c++

У меня есть куча классов.
Я в цикле хочу создать объект каждого класса и вызвать у него определенный метод. Все классы являются дочерними( и внучатыми) одного родительского.
Как можно это реализовать?

```
class A {
    void f();
}
class B: public A { }
class C: public A { }
class D: public C { }
class E: public A { }
class F: public A { }
class G: public A { }

void main () {
    // тут волшебный код который вы мне сейчас подскажите
    // и в итоге получится массив классов mClass[7]
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        mClass[i] t;
        t.f();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам нужен другой класс, который умеет по запросу создавать эти, фабрика, так сказать... Простейший способ - метод `A create(int i);` со switch внутри

Comment: тогда уж так: A[] createArray();

Comment: Сегодня вам нужен массив, завтра любая другая конфигурация этих классов.

Comment: Вы делаете что-то не то. Если вы добавляете объекты в общий список, значит вас должно устраивать то, что вы не в курсе конкретной реализации этих объектов. Должно быть достаточно общего интерфейса. Узнать, какой конкретно у вас класс по указателю A можно, пытаясь выполнить reinterpret_cast в дочерние классы, но в контексте ООП - это некорректное желание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элементами массива могут быть только объекты одного и того же типа. Если хочется запихнуть в него объекты разных классов, то это будет кортеж. Создать кортеж и вызвать метод для каждого объекта можно так:

```
::std::tuple<A, B, C, D, E, F, G> items{};
::std::apply([](auto &&... item){(item.f(),...);}, items);
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HRwCbp71fmWeQciG)

Comment: а можете подробнее расписать что значит `&&` и что значит `...`? что будет на месте `auto`?

Comment: @KtoTo `auto &&... item` - это параметры (каждый из которых является универсальной ссылкой) для generic lambda, этот кусок будет раскрыт в `A & item1, B & item2 ` и.д. `(item.f(),...)` - это fold expression, этот кусок будет раскрыт в `item1.f(), item2.f(),` и т.д.